# Cannot open slime-helper.el

Tags: debian, emacs, crunchbang, lisp

I'm trying to install slime on a debian wheezy distro 64 bit called Crunchbang, trying to install common lisp, followed [this tutorial](http://www.mohiji.org/2011/01/31/modern-common-lisp-on-windows/), although the title says it's for windows, I installed it on linux and slime seems to work perfectly (or so i think).

However, I see this error

`Cannot open slime-helper.el`

so i ran

`emacs --debug-init`

and got this error

[image]
`
Should I care about it? And if so, how to fix it?

note that i have sbcl, not clisp, and that my `.emacs` fle looks like this

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

Comment: if the image isn't too clear, right click, view image, it will be so big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the file `/home/elie/quicklisp/slime-helper.el` does not exist.

So, does it?  What do you see when you do `ls /home/elie/quicklisp/slime-helper.el`?

Incidentally, you do not need `expand-file-name` in `load`.